# What is the best Screen Recording Software for a low end PC?

Tags: windows, screen-recording

My System is pretty low end in terms of specs, but I want to record it's Screen while I work on it, mainly while using ***Unity***.

**Which is the best Screen Recording Software for the purpose**

*My PC Specs :

OS : Windows 10

Processor : i5-2520M

RAM : 4GB DDR3

Graphics Card : None (Intel Integrated Graphics 32 MB)*

Comment: There are many Unitys out there. Do you mean [this Unity](https://unity.com/de) for game development? I guess that'll be hard, since Unity might use a lot of RAM already.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 comes with its own screen capture software. It's part of the 'Game Bar'. You can open it by pressing <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.
Since it's part of Windows 10 by default, I *imagine* it being optimized, but my specs are a little better, so I can't tell for sure (besides, it *still* is Microsoft).

Comment: Unfortunately this software is not working on a hardware without advanced graphik card.

Answer (score 2):

[VSDC free screen recorder](https://www.videosoftdev.com/free-screen-recorder) should be just the right program for a low end PC. My PC has almost exactly the same specs and the program still works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Please explain your answer with a few facts or screenshots

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Which screenshots?

Comment: Just being helpful.  Of the program its menu, its settings.  Whatever, to substantiate your answer.  Otherwise your answer is in danger of getting deleted.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Added screenshot.

Comment: And I have upvoted it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You call it low? I have recorded on my old Windows XP PC with single core processor and less then 1 GB RAM. So here a list of free software solutions:

[Debut Video Capture and Screen Recorder Software](https://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/index.html)
[Free Cam](https://www.freescreenrecording.com/)
[DVDVideoSoft’s Free Screen Video Recorder](https://www.dvdvideosoft.com/de/products/dvd/Free-Screen-Video-Recorder.htm)
[ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) (even open source)
[CamStudio](https://camstudio.org/)
[Ezvid](https://www.ezvid.com/download)
[TinyTake](https://tinytake.com/)
[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) (open source and cross platform)

Answer (score 1):

Something like ffmpeg that's run through CLI should be fast: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop ShareX that was recommended by someone also uses ffmpeg under the hood and is more user-friendly if needed.

Comment: I have mentioned ShareX.

Answer (score 1):

I use [screenrec](https://screenrec.com/screen-recorder/).  It is free

> **Free Screen Recorder**
> ScreenRec is a free screen recorder with no watermark that lets you capture your desktop in one click and share instantly.
>
> - Get started in 60 seconds
> - Record computer audio
> - Record your voice
> - Record your webcam
> - No watermarks or time limits
> - Lightweight screen recorder (no lag)
> - Cloud Recording technology

It has a mini-tool-bar that you can pin anywhere

[image]

This is the setup screen.  I used it to screenshot it.

[image: screenshot]

I am not associated with it in any way.